# htaccess issue accessing folders on sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have bluehost with a wildcard SSL certificate and I'm having an issue accessing folders in the subdomain. bv-site is in a sub folder called bv-site/  when I go to https://bv-site.kavablue.com/js for example it shows the contents of the top level folder??  Help would be amazing, Bluhost requires two .htaccess files one in the top level and one in the sub domains folder below are the files.

```
#top level folder .htaccess file
# boatvibes site
#.htaccess WildCard SSL 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bv-site.kavablue.com$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bv-site/    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bv-site/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bv-site.kavablue.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ bv-site/index.html [L]

#file in /bv-site
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kavablue\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kavablue\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/bv-site\.kavablue\.com\/" [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>

#options
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^.*(de|es|fr|it|ja|ru|en).*$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=prefer-language:%1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bv/
```

be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bv-site/
```